# about codimension two foliation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, foliations

Are there examples of codimension 2 foliations on closed compact 4-manifolds or 5-manifold

I am curious about examples of codimension
Are there any previous studies or lecture notes of foliation structures of codimension 2 on, for example, dimension 4 or 5 manifolds?
Also, what are the differences and difficulties between codimension 2 foliation structures and codimension 1 foliation structures?

Comment: There are certainly results. For example, up to isotopy there are non-trivial product structures on $S^1 \times D^3$ and $S^1 \times D^4$.  They are trivial up to diffeomorphism.   I suppose it all depends on what features of these foliations you are interested in.

Comment: I am interested in codim 2 foliation example and its classifying. in particular tautness and Reeb component,  I'm interested in classifying whether codimension 2 leaf have a Reeb component or tautness.